# how to invert string value from database to make the checkbox check/uncheck - VB.NET

Tags: database, string, vb.net, checkbox, boolean

I am creating a CRUD system on VB.Net, and I have converted my checkbox values to string upon adding to the database. Now, I wanted to invert the values. I want to make the checkbox state set to checked/unchecked based on the string value from the database whenever I select a row from datagrid.

Here are my checklist items from my **add/create form** [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWGGm.png), I want them to appear as text on my database so I converted it to string. Now on my search form, I want those check boxes to appear checked/unchecked depending on the string value on my database whenever I selected a row. I hope this clear things up. thank you for helping out.

This is the code I am trying to work on:

```
CheckOne2One.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("Class").Value)
```

Comment: Why would you convert a Boolean to a String when adding to the database? What database is it?

Comment: What are the values in the database? "Yes"/"No"? "True"/"False"? Something else?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "invert"?

Comment: Most databases have a dedicated Boolean data type that maps directly to the `Boolean` data type in VB.NET when using ADO.NET, so there should be no conversion necessary. In Access, the data type is `Yes/No` and in SQL Server it is `bit`. It's almost certain that you're trying to solve a problem that you created in the first place. If you just use the correct data types then there's no problem to solve.